# Moment date issue when manipulating dates

Tags: javascript, c#, date, datetime, momentjs

All the problem starts when I detect an odd behavior: I had a long number that means "the number of milliseconds since 0001/01/01", then in C# date time when I use the `AddMilliseconds` get a different date value that the one returned from the moment one, in one hour different. eg.

```
new DateTime().AddMilliseconds(63613091700000);  =>  {10/26/2016 3:15:00 PM}
moment([1]).add(63613091700000).toDate()         =>  Wed Oct 26 2016 16:15:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

In C# get the 15:15h and in the moment 16:15!!!

That blown my mind, so I search the error, and I find it:

```
moment([1]).toDate()   =>  Mon Jan 01    1 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

The problem was that when I create the moment from a custom date (`moment([1])`) it use the `GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)` but when apply the moment `add` method it returns `GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`! Also check that creating the moment date by `moment()` or using the javascript date `new Date()` also use the `GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`. So that is the problem.

My question is, why does this happen? Is it an issue?

Comment: It happens because that is the timezone set on the system you're running your javascript on. Also, going back to when Jesus was born, seems like a strange thing to do, generally javascript starts counting from 1970, not 0001.

Comment: Store and manipulate all dates in UTC. The last thing you do with a datetime before putting it in the UI is format it using the user's local time zone/DST settings, and the first thing you do with a datetime after receiving it from the UI is convert it to UTC.

Comment: @adeneo Pretty sure Jesus wasn't born until 0001/12/25. Plenty of time.

Comment: What @EdPlunkett said. UTC all the way, otherwise keeping track of timezones/timespans will fry your head.

Comment: .Net uses by default 0001, I have no problem with that. What I'm talking here is not about to store the datetime, it is about the odd moment behavior, I think it shouldn't use two different times, I think it should be consequent, and use the same user time.

Comment: You should be able to pass the number of milliseconds directly into `moment()` rather than using `moment([1]).add()`. Also, the Date object in JavaScript is stored as the "number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970 12:00:00 AM **UTC**", as adeneo suggests. If you defined a `DateTime JsEpoch = DateTime.ParseExact("1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z", "o", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);`, you can use milliseconds since then. For UTC in moment, use `moment.utc(milliseconds)`.

Answer (score 1):

ECMAScript treats daylight saving rules as if they always applied, even before daylight saving was introduced.

When you create a Date for 0001-01-01 in host set to US EST time zone, there was no daylight saving (because US EDT runs from March to early November) so a UTC time value is calculated for 0001-01-01T00:00:00-0500 or 0001-01-01T05:00:00Z (they are the same moment in time).

On the same host, when you add enough milliseconds to get to 2016-10-26 15:15:00-0500 in a place that has daylight saving on that day, then the time will increment 1 hour because of the different offset for daylight saving, so the time is shown as 16:15:00 or in full: 2016-10-26T16:15:00-0400.

But note that 2016-10-26T15:15:00-0500 and 2016-10-26T16:15:00-0400 are exactly the same moment in time (and equivalent to 2016-10-26T20:15:00Z), the only difference is the timezone offset.

If you want to display dates and times for a particular timezone other than UTC, use [moment-timezone.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Answer (score 0):

I have found what is happening, but not how to handle it:
The problem is the `Is Daylight Saving Time` of javascript.

From http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-daylight-saving-time/:

```
moment([2011, 2, 12]).isDST(); // false, March 12 2011 is not DST
moment([2011, 2, 14]).isDST(); // true, March 14 2011 is DST
```

The thing is that when I do `moment([1]).add(63613091700000).toDate()` it calculates in the right way, but the result datetime is in DST so it transform it. I doesn't want that behavior this time.

Comment: **All ECMAScript Date objects are UTC**, they do not have a time zone offset. The host system offset is used to calculate the UTC value when creating the date, then also used to generate a "local" string and when non–UTC methods are used. If you want to see UTC time, use *toISOString*.